# vue3 Leaflet components syntax variant: how caching and using plugins for that

Tags: leaflet, cache, leaflet-plugins, vue.js

I am wondering how to use plugins with component style of Leaflet and specifically how to use the pouchDB plugin for caching tiles.

I already got that running with the variant, where you build up the map via js:

```
//on my vue component (options api) setup function
 this.map = L.map('map').setView(this.mapCenter, this.zoom);
```

using this setup, I can easily do:

```
import L from "leaflet"
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'; window.PouchDB = PouchDB;
import "leaflet.tilelayer.pouchdbcached"
```

when loading things.

How would I get plugins running when using Leaflet as components:

```
import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css"
import {
    LMap,
    LTileLayer
} from "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet"
```

with the template syntax:

```
<template>
   <l-map> ... </l-map>
</tempalte>
```

I checked the docs but did not find quite a way how to do so. What have I missed?